# Basic PHP OOP for Regex Login - What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: php, regex, oop, authentication

I am re-learning php after almost 10 years of not using it, and now I want to re-learn it, and correctly this time, but I seem to not be grasping OOP, what am I doing wrong here?

Trying to make a basic login script.

login.php

```
$act = isset( $_POST['act'] ) ? $_POST['act'] : '' ;

switch ($act) {
case 'login':

$uname = new CleanData($_POST['username']);
$uname-> set_minlength('8');
$uname-> set_maxlength('40');
$uname-> set_pregtype('match');
$uname-> set_regex('/^[\w@._-]{8,40}$/');
$uname-> cleaner();

etc...
```

class file

```
class CleanData
{
var $data;
var $minlength;
var $maxlength;
var $pregtype;
var $regex;

function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

function set_minlength($minlength){
    $this->$minlength = $minlength;
}

function set_maxlength($maxlength){
    $this->$maxlength = $maxlength;
}

function set_pregtype($pregtype){
    $this->$pregtype = $pregtype;
}

function set_regex($regex){
    $this->$regex = $regex;
}

function cleaner(){

    print $this->pregtype."\n";

    if ($this->pregtype == 'match') {
        print "MATCH REGEX HERE";
    }elseif ($this->pregtype == 'replace') {
        print "REPLACE REGEX HERE";
    }else{
        print "UNKNOWN REGEX TYPE";
    }

}

}
```

I get "UNKNOWN REGEX TYPE", which I am sure makes perfect sense, but I dont understand why. Am I even using OOP correctly by writing this class?

Its really hard to re-learn something correctly after doing it wrong, I just want to write it fast the way I know how instead of re-learning everything and writing at a snails pace, but I must stay strong...

I appreciate the help, I always wanted to post here, but I suck at asking for help, always want to do everything myself.

Comment: `$this->data` <-> `$this->$regex` See the difference ?

Comment: Thank you all, I figured it would be something stupid I overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->$minlength = $minlength;
       ^----NO, don't do this
```

You're trying to set a dynamic attribute based on your argument, which makes no sense at all. e.g.

```
set_minlength(42)  -> `$this->42 = 42`
set_maxlength(42)  -> `$this->42 = 42`
```

Now you've not only overwritten the minlength value, you have no way of know what the heck this mysterious `$this->42` really is. How would `get_minlength()` work? `$this->????`?

Try

```
$this->minlength = $minlength;
       ^---note, no $
```

and similar for all of your OTHER methods as well.

Comment: + the keyword: `var` is not so up to date :]

Comment: What do I use instead of var, public?

Comment: @IWriteBugs, `protected` is usually best. A declaration of `public` would permit external amendment, which is not good practice, and `private` means that a child class can't see the property, which is usually _too_ locked down.

Comment: Thanks Marc B & halfer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these:

```
$this->minlength = $minlength;

$this->maxlength = $maxlength;

 $this->pregtype = $pregtype;

 $this->regex = $regex;
```

Here you are assigning the values to the variables, that are declared above.

Comment: Would you kindly outline (as an edit to your answer) what you have changed here? We encourage answerers to include a sentence or two to explain what the problem is and how the new code fixes the problem.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time I banged my head over an obvious mistake.